# How to launch an apk via ADB with console arguments on Android

Tags: android, shell, unity-game-engine, adb

How to launch an application with console arguments via adb on Android 10?

Search in docs https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Googled for two days, everywhere they write what they need like this:
`adb shell am start -S -D -n projectname.app/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity --es args '"-runTests"'`

[Tried some more options but nothing worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxNzB.png)

The application is a game on Unity, there I display System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
[directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhlu9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a misunderstanding because Android apps do not have command-line arguments as all app processes are forked from the dalvik virtual machine process.

The options you set on `am start` are intent options, so you have to get those options e.g. in `onCreate` of the `UnityPlayerActivity` class:

```
String arg = intent.getStringExtra("args");
Log.d("", arg); // would in your example output "-runTests"
```